# integral relation related to uniqueness for ODE's

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

My question appeared from one statement about non-uniqueness for ODE's. Consider a continuous function $\theta:(0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ such that 
$$
\int^1_0 \frac{\theta(s)}{s}ds=\infty.
$$
Of course, there are infinitely many solutions for the Cauchy problem
$$
\begin{cases}
u'(t)=\frac{1+\theta(t)}{t}u(t) \\
u(0)=0
\end{cases}
$$
In fact, $u(t)=ce^{-\int^1_t \frac{1+\theta(s)}{s}ds}$ will be a solution for every $c.$ The problem is to rewrite the equation in the form $u'(t)=f(t,u(t))$ where $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}.$ This is possible when I know that $\theta(t)e^{-\int^1_t\frac{\theta(s)}{s}ds}\to 0,$ $t\to 0.$

So, the question is whether the condition $\int^1_0 \frac{\theta(s)}{s}ds=\infty$ implies $\theta(t)e^{-\int^1_t\frac{\theta(s)}{s}ds}\to 0,$ $t\to 0?$

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^1\frac{\theta(s)}{s}\,ds=\infty$ implies
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\exp\bigl(-\int^1_t\frac{\theta(s)}{s}ds\bigr)=0.
$$ 
Since $\theta$ is continuous,
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\theta(t)\exp\bigl(-\int^1_t\frac{\theta(s)}{s}ds\bigr)=0.
$$
In fact, continuity is not needed. It is enough that $\theta$ is bounded on $[0,a)$ for some $a>0$.

Comment: I do not assume continuity at 0, in fact $\theta$ is defined and continuous on (0,1]. It may be unbounded in the neighborhood of 0

Comment: I misunderstood.